# Resize event not triggered when resizing to 0 height?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, dom, dom-events

i am currently looking at a resizing function when i came across a strange issue. When i resize the window to the minimum height (only showing the top window bar with minimise and close on it) there is no javascript event fired.

I can see it working at all other heights and widths but no event is fired when resizing to the minimum height. I alos tried to log the document body and check it is not nulled at this point, it is not...

Notes:

> Im using Google Chrome (v66) latest.
> windows 10 (doubt this is really relevant, unless someone using mac etc says it is working in their chrome version)
>
> Update to the above: Ive noticed my original solution works on chrome in mac (latest version 66), but no event occurs in chrome (latest version 66) on Windows.

This is simply javascript and i cannot understand why the event is not triggered when the height is 0 (68 is the minimum height i am able to resize to with the event still triggering, after that there is only the top toolbar visible).

i have a small html test to try below to see what im talking about - alternatively it would be very simple to create a demo anyway.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Open a new window, and resize the width and height of the new window.</p>

<button onclick="openWin()">Create window</button>
<button onclick="resizeWinTo()">Resize the window to 800px * 600px</button>
<button onclick="resizeWinBy()">Make the new window smaller</button>

<script>
var myWindow;

function openWin() {
   myWindow = window.open("", "", "width=250, height=250");
   myWindow.onresize = function (event) { 
       console.log(myWindow.outerHeight);
       console.log(myWindow.outerWidth);
   };
}

function resizeWinTo() {
   myWindow.resizeTo(800, 600);
   myWindow.focus();
}

function resizeWinBy() {
   myWindow.resizeBy(-100, -50);
   myWindow.focus();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Any suggestions where i could send this to get more information, such as the chrome developers for windows?

Answer (score 1):

***why the event is not triggered when the height is 0?***

It is because you have reached the minimum outer height of the window(68, which is the height of the title/top bar in your case) you cannot go below the minimum outer height.

If you want to get content's height. You should use **innerHeight** instead of outerHeight

For that change

```
console.log(myWindow.outerHeight);
```

to

```
console.log(myWindow.innerHeight);
```

Since outerHeight is considering height of title/top bar in your case.

Quoting from [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window)

> outerHeight : Gets the height of the outside of the browser window.
>
> innerHeight : Gets the width of the outside of the browser window.

Comment: no my intent is to use outerHeight because this is the value set when using the resizeTo() method. You have overlooked the question, my problem is that the resized event is not even firing from the javascript - meaning i get no console logs. Both inner and outer are valid - the need for myself to use the outer size version means i can better handle the size without knowing a users toolbars etc.

Comment: I updated the answer, answering why there is no logs.

Comment: Hi @user158, thanks for the update. could you please inform me on which browser and os you are using? Ive noticed my original solution works on chrome in mac (latest version 66), but no event occurs in chrome (latest version 66) on Windows.

Comment: I am using Linux Mint 18.3 with Chrome Version 66.0.3359.117 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: @Im-Harrison My observations: 
On Linux Minimum (Address bar + Top bar)
     Inner Height: 1, Inner Width: 110, 
     Outer Width: 29, Outer Height: 110 
On Windows 8 Chrome 66 Minimum (Addressbar + Top bar) 
     Outer Height: 68, Outer Width: 140, 
     Inner Height:1, Inner Width: 124

Comment: As you may notice in both cases I did not able to get 0. Sometimes even  though I minimized the window to the minimum, it gave me different values although window was at the same minimum. I suppose giving different results at the same minimum may be related to how JavaScript engine works internally(caching?). As I said in the answer you cannot go below the minimum outer height which is the height of the top bar + address bar

Comment: yes but i cannot get the event at all after any height lower than 68, i wonder if taking a video would help illustrate this better, i may upload one tomorrow to show exactly what i mean. Im not sure if somewhere my question is too unclear. resizing the height in chrome to < 68, which then sets it to 68 (the min with the chrome bar) does not throw the window resized event. Sorry if im not understanding you perfectly but you make it sound like you are seeing this event, therefore i will upload a video tomorrow to show you the issue. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can dispatch the event 'resize' on the new window by checking if limit of the new window is reach.

Possible that "Chrome" not resize when you not need to resize your window.

Check the code bellow, maybe that will help you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>

        <p>Open a new window, and resize the width and height of the new window.</p>

        <button onclick="openWin()">Create window</button>
        <button onclick="resizeWinTo()">Resize the window to 800px * 600px</button>
        <button onclick="resizeWinBy()">Make the new window smaller</button>

        <script>
            var myWindow;

            function openWin() {
                myWindow = window.open("", "", "width=250, height=250");
                myWindow.resizeBy = function (deltaX, deltaY) {
                    var X = parseInt(myWindow.innerWidth) + parseInt(deltaX)
                            , Y = parseInt(myWindow.innerHeight) + parseInt(deltaY);
                    myWindow.resizeTo(X > 0 ? X : 0, Y > 0 ? Y : 0);
                    myWindow.focus();
                };
                myWindow.onresize = function (event) {
                    console.log('outerHeight -> ' + myWindow.outerHeight);
                    console.log('outerWidth -> ' + myWindow.outerWidth);
                };
            }

            function resizeWinTo() {
                myWindow.resizeTo(800, 600);
                myWindow.focus();
            }

            function resizeWinBy() {
                var prevValY = myWindow.outerHeight
                    , prevValX = myWindow.outerWidth
                    , deltaX = -100
                    , deltaY = -50;
                myWindow.resizeBy(deltaX, deltaY);
                if ((prevValX == myWindow.outerWidth || (myWindow.outerWidth - prevValX) > deltaX)
                        && (prevValY == myWindow.outerHeight || myWindow.outerHeight == 0)) {
                    myWindow.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
                }
                myWindow.focus();
            }
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i looked into this and have tested it - unfortunately it makes no difference. once the height is dragged to the minimum there is no console log created because the event is not being fired still. Seems like a strange issue to me. Thanks for the attempt